# Records from one Microsoft Access table not following the same order as specified

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables that I am working with in my Access Database, (table1 & table2) table2 is used as a copy of table1. 
 I have a button on my form that when clicked runs a VBA Subroutine that runs a query that copies everything in table1 and stores it in table2, sorted by the ID ascending. 
 When I run the query in datasheet mode it orders things perfectly fine, but when I run the query, table2's data is all out of order.

Here is the Query in question:
`SELECT table1.* INTO table2 FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.ID;` 

It's a very small query so I'm unsure where exactly my issue lies, any help would be really appreciated.

I tried deleting the table before hand to see if that would work but the data still ends up unsorted.

Comment: Not a ms-access user, but if stores tables like other relational database, then sorting is non-existent. Your queries would use ORDER BY to display how you wish.

Comment: Also note that indexes are not copied when you use the statement you are giving us. When you want/need a more exact copy you can use [DoCmd.CopyObject method (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.copyobject#example) (from VBA)

Answer (score 0):

When you think of tables, it is best to think of them as a container for the data, but there is no concept of "order" or "sorted". I know in Access you can double click a table and it looks like a spreadsheet, but try to avoid thinking of it like a spreadsheet.

A query, view, or report, is what you can use to extract data from tables, which is where you can choose to sort and order any way you choose.

MS Access has a sort/filter group that lets you sort and filter the data in the table while you're looking at it on your screen - which can be confusing when you hear me tell you this. But trust me, never trust a table to maintain a specific order of the rows by itself.

Therefore, if you are inserting data into a table like in your example, the `ORDER BY` clause is basically useless. If you really do want these inserted into the table in a way that will let you logically sort them later, then you need to think about inserting some sort of timestamp, or calculated indicator that can be used for sorting when you write a query or report.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not your main concern,so its maybe a bit of an overload.
Anyhow, if you don't use TSQL i prefer to work with a dao.recordset to copy data.
It's a matter of taste i suppose.
So, if you alter this code to your needs, you have 100% control of what happens where :

```
Private Function copyTables()
    
    Dim rstFrom As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstTo As DAO.Recordset
    '
    Set rstFrom = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table1 order by Id Asc", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rstTo = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table2 where 1 = 0", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    '
    Do While rstFrom.EOF = False
        
        rstTo.AddNew
        rstTo!Field1 = rstFrom!Field1
        rstTo!Field2 = rstFrom!Field2
        rstTo.Update
        rstFrom.MoveNext
        
    Loop
    '
    Set rstFrom = Nothing
    
    rstTo.Close
    
    Set rstTo = Nothing
    
    
End Function
```

By altering the line

```
select * from table1 order by Id Asc
```

to

```
select * from table1 order by Id Desc
```

you change the direction of your insert.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my issue by instead of running a regular query, I hard coded one via VBA and running the same query that way seemed to have worked properly.